Elasticity of substitution in a non-homothetic CES function
I am trying to derive the elasticity of substitution in a utility function:
$u = \Big( \sum_{} \alpha_{i}^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} (c_{it} + \overline{c}_{i})^{\frac{\sigma - 1 }{\sigma}} \Big) ^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma - 1}}$
I use the regular expression for elasticity of substitution, which is the inverse of  $- \frac{dlog(MRS_{ij})}{d log(\frac{c_it}{c_jt})}$. Since there are non-homothetic terms, I use the chain rule and take partial derivatives as follows:
$- \frac{dlog(MRS_{ij})}{d log(\frac{c_it}{c_jt})} = - \frac{dlog(MRS_{ij})}{d c_{it}}\frac{d c_{it}}{d log(\frac{c_it}{c_jt})} -  \frac{dlog(MRS_{ij})}{d c_{jt}}\frac{d c_{jt}}{d log(\frac{c_it}{c_jt})} =  \frac{1}{\sigma}\Big( \frac{c_{it}}{c_{it}+ \overline{c}_{i}} + \frac{c_{jt}}{c_{jt}+ \overline{c}_{j}} \Big) $
The elasticity of substitution is the inverse of this expression.
However, when I set the non-homotheticity parameters to 0, the elasticity becomes $\sigma/2 $, not $\sigma$. When I try to use the same approach to getting the elasticity of substitution in a CES function without non-homotheticity parameters and take partial derivatives like I did here, I also get $\sigma/2 $, not $\sigma$, unlike when I take thederivative of MRS with respect to $log(\frac{c_it}{c_jt})$, which does give me $\sigma$, but since I cannot do this in the non-homothetic case, I am trying to understand where the discrepancy comes when using partial derivatives.
So why is it that when using partial derivative the elasticity is $\sigma/2 $, not $\sigma$? And is the elasticity of substitution in the non-homothetic utility function incorrect since it is not $\sigma$ when I set the non-homotheticity parameters to 0?
